# Create semi transparent text background in slider

Tags: php, android, html, css

I am using Revolution Slider for a website project. I have background images with text in front of the image. I'm wanting to create a dark semi-transparent background for text with the color white so that the text stands out better on the images.

I have tried the following:

```
z-index: 15; 
min-width: 448px; 
max-width: 448px; 
white-space: normal; 
color: #ffffff; 
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
padding: 12px;
```

It looks great on my laptop. Exactly the way I want it. However, when viewed on my Android smart phone, the background only spans about 1/2 of the length of the text .... part of it has a background, the rest of it doesn't.

Here is a link to the page: http://rossini.us/kuecker.com/

Comment: Can you format your code?

Answer (score 0):

This particular element has a `max-height` property that's added as inline CSS, via JavaScript, as the page resizes. This is preventing the background from reaching the text size. I'm not sure what JS is adding the property, but you could override it with `max-height: none !important;`.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I tried:

style="z-index: 15; min-width: 448px; max-width: 448px; max-height: none !important; white-space: normal; color: #ffffff; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); padding: 12px;">KLG has played a vital role in 10 of our distribution centers. Their whatever it takes attitude, competitive pricing &amp; creativity is why we consistently do business with them" Engineering Manager - Major Retailer


And, I'm still having the problem with the background on only 1/2 of the text.

Comment: JavaScript is removing and replacing those inline styles. Needs to be in a style tag or your stylesheet.